# Which semiconductor manufacturer names parts RTCxxx

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am in the process of reverse engineering/tearing down a small Bluetooth speaker.  In the audio path, there are two amplifiers.  Their top markings are RTC002 and RTC005.  Note that these are NOT Real Time Clocks.  I'm positive they are amplifiers.  Google hasn't turned anything up in regard to that part number.  Any leads on the possible vendor?  I'd like to try and find a datasheet.  Thank you.

EDIT: Picture of first IC attached.  SOP-8.  Appears to be a dual op amp (left/right channels) connected as high-pass filter.  Was shocked how clear the image came out with jeweler's loop and phone camera!
[image: RTC002]

Jon, I don't know the make/model of the speakers as I came by the board second-hand.  I'll try to ask the original owner.

EDIT 2: Picture of the second IC.  MSOP-8.  Seems to be hooked up as a diff in/diff out amplifier.  There are 2 of this one, one for each channel.
[image: RTC005]

Jon, definitely not made in U.S.  Chinese ICs, perhaps?

Comment: What is the make and model number of the speaker?

Comment: Put a picture, it sometimes help.

Comment: @AKR, I Goooooooooooooogled every variation I could think of, alldatasheet.com, Ali, etc... I couldn't find anything so I'm assuming they are "Hecho en not-America". Assuming they are op-amps, how would he go about selecting an equivalent?

Comment: +1 for need picture; i.e. why are the two different?

Comment: [Richtek](http://www.richtek.com/) technology corporation have products with part names RTxxxx. But the 3rd character is a number not 'C'.

Comment: @nidhin, excellent feedback! It's not Richtek, but I appreciate the lead.

Comment: It might stand for Real Time Clock.

Comment: Looks to me like RTC is the brand name of the manufacturer, "Rsomething Technology Co" or "Rsomething Taiwan Company". Must be a big one to remark ICs or get their ICs marked with their insignia. On the other hand, in China it may be cheaper to buy bare dies and do the test and packaging yourself rather than to buy known good ICs which are tested and packaged by the manufacturer.

Comment: By the way, in case it's relevant, if you want to make your own Bluetooth speakers, get a bluetooth speaker module from some random electronics design/vendor company in HK/Shenzhen area - this stuff practically grows on trees there. And then you'll know (or at least have a general idea) which ICs you are using.